# 'Serial' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Here, I recontruct the class to composition ways. The class is listen to buffer. But, method recv like don't know what a argument **device** it. I don't know exactly the error means.

```
'Serial' object is not subscriptable
```

```
class Device():

    def open(self, port, baudrate):
        try:
            return serial.Serial(port, baudrate)
        except SerialException as e:
            error = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", str(e))

            return error

    def __state(self, device):
        if device is not False:
            if device[1] == 'Access is denied.':
                return True
            elif device[1] == 'Port is already open.':
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True

    def recv(self, device):
        while True:    
            if self.__state(device):
                buffer = device.readline()

                print(buffer)

                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print(device[0] + ' ' + device[1])

                time.sleep(1)

device = Device()

serial = device.open('COM12', 9600)

device.recv(serial)
```

Answer (score 0):

"'Serial' object is not subscriptable" means that you can't use the square bracket syntax (`someObject[n]`) with the Serial object. If you try running the following code it should reproduce the error:

```
serial.Serial("COM12", 9600)[1]
```

The problem is one the line `if device[1] == 'Access is denied.':`. You can't use the square bracket syntax with the device variable here, because it is an instance of Serial.

Comment: device attribute inside `__state` method is compare. if it already pass conditional check that return from `open()` method. Method `open()` return 2 things. If success return *object* serial else return **List** error. So inside `__state()` method the device is list attribute. So i think i can access device like list.

Comment: But, before compare `__state` method. `__state` will check there's error or not in `if device is not False:`. I read somewhere, if a variabel is not initiliaze with a value. it will return `False` boolean

Comment: The `device` parameter of the `__state` method is either a Serial object (if `open` succeeds) or a list (if `open` fails). It is never a Boolean, so the condition `device is not False` always evaluates to True. Then, in the case that `device` is a Serial object, on the next line you get the error you describe in your question.